# How to mock callback request with sinon?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon

Here is my simple app temp.js which is working fine:

```
var request = require('request');
var myRequest = request.defaults({
        agent: false,
        timeout: 5000,
        jar: false,
        followRedirect: false,
        method: 'GET'
    });

var MY_CLASS = {
    getData: function (req, res, next) {
        return myRequest({
            uri: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1',
        }, function (error, data) {
            if (error) {
                return next(error, null);
            }

            return next(null, data);
        });
    }
};

module.exports = MY_CLASS;
```

And I call it from temp2.js:

```
const MY_CLASS = require('./temp.js');

MY_CLASS.getData('test', 'test', function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log(data.statusCode);
    }
});
```

Now trying to use sinon in my unit test but how do I really stub/mock it properly? Not sure if I should stub request or export myRequest... I need to get a fake response from https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1. Here I'm stubbing getData but not request itself.. It works but how do I stub request?

```
const sinon = require("sinon");
const MY_CLASS = require('../temp.js');

describe('test', function(done) {
   before(()=>{
        sinon
        .stub(MY_CLASS, 'getData')
        .yields(null, {statusCode: 200});
   });
    after(()=>{
        MY_CLASS.getData.restore();
    });

    it.only('test', function(done) {
        function cb(err, data) { 
            data.statusCode.should.equal(200);
            done();
        }
        MY_CLASS.getData('test', 'test', cb);           
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Instead of using

```
var myRequest = request.defaults({
        agent: false,
        timeout: 5000,
        jar: false,
        followRedirect: false,
        method: 'GET'
    });
```

I do it in MY_CLASS:
instead

```
return myRequest({
```

I do

```
return request.get({}
```

Now you can stub it properly